# Cucumber test fails on unscrollable page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

Here is a test (I've opened the inspector during the test and that's definitely the element hierarchy):

```
within('table.foo') do
  find("tr#foo_#{ @foo.id }").click
end
```

Calling `find()` on the element returns:

```
could not be scrolled into view (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
```

I have a pretty good idea why--the page renders a single db entry created for the purpose of the test, and so the document doesn't extend past the window, making it unscrollable, which I think is what's throwing this error.

I have tried updating geckodriver to no avail.

Is there a method in cucumber that doesn't prompt scrolling? Would be better than a) testing in a really tiny window or b) creating more test data just to stretch the document.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug that exists in an older version of chromedriver that is caused with newer/later versions of Chrome. The bug is the driver would lose the ability to scroll the tab in focus.

I would recommend downloading the latest driver and replacing the one you are using.

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have mentioned I'm using Firefox, hence the geckodriver update. A geckodriver update didn't work, but I think I'll update chromedriver and see how the test behaves in Chrome. Thanks!